# Disappearing polygons when editing in QField

Tags: polygon-creation, qfield

I have created a project on my desktop in QGIS 3.22. It has a large TIF file which seems to be causing problems with the upload to Qfield cloud so i opted to transfer the project files to my phone and store them in a 'QGIS' folder.

On doing so, i have gone into Qfield and opened via a local directory found the .QGZ project file and opened it. I have a geopackage polygon layer where i want to create and add polygons into this layer in the field. On testing it i draw the polygons but then as soon as i tick it to add to the map they dissapear behind the satellite imagery.

It seems this might be that i need to put the polygon layer above the sat imagery in the layers but i don't know how to move it. The opacity on the poluygon layer is 100%

Comment: You need to tell more about your project setting, you don't give enough information to troubleshot …

Answer (score 0):

Just open the project in QGIS, look in the layer panel and drag the polygon layer above the image layer, save and close QGIS.

If that didn't work open the "Layer Order Panel" and reorder your layer there too (or uncheck the "control rendering order" box at the bottom